# Can you perform an operation on a complex number that creates a higher dimensional number.

Tags: complex-numbers, quaternions

I was thinking about how the square root of a number can be solved by pushing the number into the complex plain so the though arose to me: Is there an operation on some complex number that creates an higher dimensional number like a quaternion?

Comment: Great question: The complex numbers are algebraically closed, meaning that given any polynomial with coefficients in $\mathbb C$, it has $n$ roots in $\mathbb C$, where $n$ is the degree of the polynomial. So, roots would not suffice. In general, there really isn't any operation that would get you from $\mathbb C$ to a quarternion space since the latter is not commutative, while the former is.

Comment: In the same spirit where complexes aim at solving $x^2=-1$, there is this paper proposing a number system to solve $|z|^2=i$ https://arxiv.org/pdf/2012.00841.pdf. I don't know what it worth.

Comment: You can define the operation $(a+bi)°(c+di)=a+bi+cj+dk$. It answers your question. It creates a quaternion out of two complex numbers. But it doesn't have nice properties. It isn't even commutative. But you just wanted an operation.

Comment: The square root operation is really just solving an algebraic equation. Since $\Bbb C$ is already algebraically closed, no such "operation" can yield quaternions. Unless you're adjoining *additional* solutions, in which case there is no "square root" operation, really.

Comment: @zwim That is an amazing paper. Thanks.